# UX for non-traditional working time

Tags: info-visualisation, information-architecture, information-design

This is my first post so please don't be critical with me if I do something wrong.

So what is my case - Everyone knows the standard method to visualize the working hours of business:

[image: Standart working hours for business]

---

But what is if the working hours for business are not always on the same day? For example, business works from `Mon 4 am - Tue 1 am`, `Tue 4 am - Wen 1 am`... and so on. It's a little confusing for the user when you present information like this:

[image]

---

BTW: I show current time and status of the business (open/closed), but I'm not sure are this solve problem with visualization.

So folks, what do you think on this case?

Comment: For context: What kind of business is this? Where are these opening hours shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the business opens from (very) early in the morning through to (quite) late the following night, it may not be *immediately* obvious if presented in the "normal" form (it took me a couple of passes to parse it properly). A different approach might be to highlight when you are closed:

**Hours: All Day, Every Day, *except* 1am to 4am**

I've rolled-up all days into one line, since the times are the same, but you could list it day-by-day if preferred:

**Hours:**

- **Monday: All Day *except* 1am to 4am**
- **Tueday: All Day *except* 1am to 4am**
- **...**

Comment: A great solution for most humans. I wonder what havoc this would play on things like SEO and Yelp.

Comment: @AustinFrench No idea... but – depending how "clever" they are – it's plausible they could be confused by the original format where the "start" time is later than the "end" time.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is clear to the user. Logically 00:00 - 01:00 is the next day already. But from a users perspective Monday 04:00 - 01:00 is absolutely understandable.

As a reference you could use google maps an look up the opening hours of some businesses. They do it exactly this way.

Comment: I'd disagree that it's _immediately_ clear... it took me a couple of skims to realize it's open from (very) early Monday morning to (quite) late Tuesday night.  Though the type of establishment might make this more obvious.

Comment: I'd say this is 87% correct. The last 13% is probably cultural. So I would add, use the common time format. 1:00 is pretty universal, 01:00 is slightly less, and 1:00 AM is what an American would expect. In fact seeing 4:00 AM - 1:00 AM is very easy to understand that's it's open for all but 3 hours a day.

Comment: @AustinFrench I absolutely agree with you. The format should always be localised.

Answer (score 1):

I think the order is fine and totally legible. What I would recommend is that you separate the times like so...

[image]

Giving white space between the hours and the days helps the readability massively.

Comment: I see how you added AM and PM... ;)